# how can I grab an image from html, the image is not in img tag but under div class='blah blah'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I learned today how to grab an image from the internet using `BeautifulSoup.select('blahblah')` on Python and how to download them on my mac.

I was able to download photos which were in the `img` tag and find them like so:
`src='http or // blah blah'`.

But I can not find any `.jpg` or `.png` parts under `'div' class='something else'`.

The image I wanted to download is not just an image but also seems to have other functions such as showing login popup and has a button on it to make the image bigger.

```
import lxml
import bs4
import requests

rec = requests.get('https://www.pinterest.com/pin/701294973197421148/')
soup_rec = bs4.BeautifulSoup(rec.text, 'lxml')

soup_rec

soup_rec.select('div.zI7.iyn.Hsu') # I just type this way to try anything.
```

The image I tried to download is an actress's photo in the middle of a Pinterest page.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Is it dynamic content? Do you evaluate the script code? Is the image url in the CSS?

Comment: I don't know what dynamic content is, because i just learned how to scrape images so I am just practicing what `I just have learned. sorry I am not able to give more specific information such as if the image url in the CSS? I didn't learn it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will require [`selenium`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) for this purpose as this is a dynamic website:

```py
import bs4 as Bs
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_PATH = 'path/to/your/executable'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

driver.get('https://www.pinterest.com/pin/701294973197421148/')

page_src = Bs.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

img = page_src.find("div",{"class":"zI7 iyn Hsu"}).find("img")

print(img.get_attribute_list("src")[0])
```

gives me:

```
'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ac/8b/d7/ac8bd7a2ff22210e8592a2aae202490d.jpg'
```

---

You can use [this guide](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/guide-scraping-dynamic-web-pages-python-selenium) on how to use selenium to scrape dynamic websites.

Comment: Oh! thanks! I need to look up what selenium is and how the web driver works and how to use them! 
those kind of websites are called dynamic websites, need to look it up.